# Grafana / Graphite - Display number of series where count > 0

Tags: graphite, grafana

I have some user level histogram metrics. 
I want to display a singlestat in grafana that shows me the number of series where the count in `histogram.bin_5000` > 0.

I can get it to display the number of series with `countSeries`.  But, can't seem to get a filter to remove the series which are below a certain value.

#### With Count Series

[image]

#### With Count Series AND removeBelowValue

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The functions `removeBelow*` and `removeAbove*` (including `removeBelowValue`) actually **do not remove series**, rather **just set `null`** (`None`) to matching datapoints.

There are two solutions:

1. use [`removeEmptySeries`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.removeEmptySeries), that removes all metrics that have only null datapoints.  This will also remove null metrics that existed before `removeBelow*`.
2. instead of `remove*`-family use [`maximumBelow/Above`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.maximumAbove), [`minimumBelow/Above`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.minimumAbove). that remove (sic!) series

Comment: thank you for that explanation!  I tried your suggestion of using the maximumAbove/Below but it doesn't seem to be filtering it out still.  I switched to a data table view so i could see the results returned and took a screenshot here: http://www.screencast.com/t/eBWDuRigSkAx